# Can't acess to the event target of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access to the clicked element with the click event listener.
I'm doing it this way :

```
$("body")[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var domElement = $(event.target)
  console.log(domElement)
  if($(domElement).is('a, a *')){
    localStorage.setItem('TEST CLOSEST','NEXT PAGE'); 
    action.type = "Link click";
    action.xpath = xpath;
    localStorage.setItem('INPUT',JSON.stringify(action)); 
}      
}, true);
```

But when I try to log the dom element it returns it to me this object :

```
jQuery.fn.init [input.gLFyf.gsfi]
```

So when I try to do it this way :

```
$(event.target[0])
```

it logs me this object which is not I want

```
jQuery.fn.init {}
```

How can I access to the first logged object please ?

Comment: `event.target[0]` does not exist. You mean `$(event.target)[0]` or simply `event.target`, but what is the point of that? Does `$(event.target)` itself not work here?

Comment: It does work, but I don't know how to access to the attributes of the target, for example when I try to get nodeList or Childs or stuff I can't do it.